# Convert date of format char - 20260310 to 03-10-26

Tags: r, date, stringr

I know it can somehow be achieved using stringr but wanted to check if there is any easy way? sorry for asking this simple question

Answer (score 2):

`%Y` and `%y` represent years with and without century respectively.

```r
x <- "20260310"

format(strptime(x, "%Y%m%d"), "%m-%d-%y")
# [1] "03-10-26"
```

1. `strptime(x, "%Y%m%d")` converts the date string to a standard `Date` object in R.
2. `format(..., "%m-%d-%y")` changes its appearance and the output is always character.

Comment: thanks, but after doing this strangely the type of data is still char and im not able to subtract one date from other. date 1 - type char - value- "2021-31-12" date 2- type char-value "2026-03-10"

Comment: Of course! The standard format of a date object in R is `yyyy-mm-dd`. `format()` make it change to what you want, but it'll be converted to character. Some packages support other formats, e.g. `zoo` has a special date object formatted as `yyyy-mm`. I haven't known a package supporting a date format like `03-10-26`.

Comment: So, changing the appearance of date object is always the final step of your analysis. Before this, I recommend you to use the standard date object in R. Remember to check `class(your date object)` is `Date`.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution, based on `lubridate`:

```r
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

"20260310" %>% ydm %>% {str_c(day(.), month(.), str_sub(year(.), 3, 4), sep="-")}

#> [1] "3-10-26"
```

Comment: It looks like that the date string is parsed 3 times. I'm not sure whether it influences memory or speed or not if the data are large.

Comment: Thanks, @DarrenTsai, for having commented my answer! I have meanwhile rephrased my code and now the date is parsed only once.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is `chron` from {chron} package:

```
x <- "20260310"
x |> chron(format = "ymd") |> chron(format = "m-d-y")
#[1] 03-10-26
```

The result has "dates" format.

Answer (score 1):

Variation on the lubridate solution

```
library(lubridate)
x <- "20260310"
f <- stamp("01-10-22", orders = "%d-%Om-%y")
ymd(x) |> f()
```

stamp() produces a function, that you can apply repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
> gsub("(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})", "\\2-\\3-\\1", "20260310")
[1] "03-10-2026"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require(lubridate)
require(tidyverse)

"20260310" %>% ydm() %>% 
format("%y-%m-%d")

[1] "03-10-26"

"20260310" %>% format("%y-%m-%d") %>% ydm() %>% class()

[1] "Date"
```